# vCard кнопка для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, html5

Необходимо создать кнопку на сайте при клике на которую будет добавляться vCard(новый контакт в телефоне пользователя). Не могу найти нигде описание того как это сделать на html/js

Comment: Такое вряд ли можно сделать, в связи с политикой безопасности.

Comment: http://www.kniazev.ru/sotrudniki/764/ - вот тут это реализовано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Погуглил, в общем:

Вариант **А** (Простой)
Гуглите генераторы vCard (я нашёл вот [такой](https://vcardmaker.com/)), заполняете как хотите, после сохраняете сгенерированный файл (формат `.vcf`).

Вариант **Б** (Сложнее)
Открываете текстовый редактор (хоть блокнот), создаёте свой "код" (может есть лучше документация, но вот от Википедии - [ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80)).
Далее сохраняете как `.vcf`.